# Maintaining two copies of same Readme file in git repository

Tags: git, makefile, readme

I am building a git repository that stores a development project, and also distributes one single folder in this project as a release. I would like to have this release folder also contain an exact copy of the git repository's main Readme, such that both are always in sync.

To make a release I use a Makefile to deploy that single folder to a subtree using

```
deploy:
    git subtree push --prefix PathTo/Folder/InRepo origin upm
```

I would somehow like to copy the readme at this time (or whenever it is edited).

I just copied this makefile from somewhere and have no other experience with Makefiles.

Comment: In general, it's not a good idea to store releases or build artifacts in the repository.  If you avoid doing that, your repository will be less bloated, and this problem will go away.

Comment: The other folders are needed to develop and test this single folder, and some users will want to use these extended tools to create their own custom releases. Any ideas on how to do that with them in a separate repository?

Comment: In general, you should store your release assets somewhere not in _any_ repository.  For example, if you're using GitHub, you can store the release assets as part of a release associated with a tag.  You could use something like Artifactory.  That doesn't prevent you or others from cloning and building the repository as normal; it just means you shouldn't check them into a repository.